How to escape a GVariant dictionary in bash script
I'm writing a bash script to change the display scale:
#!/bin/bash
cmd="dconf write /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor \"{'DP-4': 7, 'eDP-1': 7}\""
$cmd

The dconf command works fine from the command line, but when I run the script above I get:
error: 0-9:unterminated string constant

Usage:
  dconf write KEY VALUE 

Write a new value to a key

Arguments:
  KEY         A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
  VALUE       The value to write (in GVariant format)

I imagine I need to escape the $cmd string somehow but I can't figure it out. Can you set me on the right track?

That is expanded to dconf write /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor '"{'\''DP-4'\'':' 7, ''\''eDP-1'\'':' '7}"' which might be not what you expected ... and it's a bad idea to run commands that way.

You should probably be using a properly quoted array rather than relying on word-splitting of the unquoted expansion $cmd - something like cmd=(dconf write /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor "{'DP-4': 7, 'eDP-1': 7}") then "${cmd[@]}". See for example How can we run a command stored in a variable?

Using the thread linked to in a comment above from @steeldriver, I was able to resolve this using a function and then calling the function when needed, which seems preferable to a quoted array when feasible:
d_write_scale() {
  dconf write /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor "{'DP-4': 7, 'eDP-1': $1}"
}

